# Match list from one file1, extract corresponding lines form file 2

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

Suppose I have a reference list, say `file1.txt`, which contains:

```
a
b
c 
d
```

and I have `file2.txt`, the data file as follows:

```
a 1 2 3
b 5 6 7
d 6 7 8
e 7 8 9
```

and output needed in `output.txt`:

```
a 1 2 3
b 5 6 7
d 6 7 8
```

I want to match IDs in `file1.txt` with first column of `file2.txt` and print the whole line (row from `file2.txt`) into `output.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}($1 in a)' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Also in perl :

```
perl -F -lane '$h{$F[0]}++;if($h{$F[0]}>=2){print $_;}' file1 file2
```

*Note:The above perl command will work provided the first file has unique ID's*

Answer (score 7):

This is what `join` is designed for:

```
$ join f1 f2
a 1 2 3
b 5 6 7
d 6 7 8
```

If you need to `sort` your files first then:

```
join <(sort f1) <(sort f2)
```